# Why is F# "Generic-izing" my discriminated union

Tags: f#, type-inference

I wrote what I thought was very straight-forward F# code, but the compiler seems to be tripping up on the type inference. Rather than inferring from the discriminated union, it's going with a generic inference. I don't understand why, though, since my code does not allow for a generic inference.

Here's the code:

```fsharp
module Log

open System

type LogInput =
    | Message of (int * string)
    | Error of Exception
    | Process of ( string * unit -> int )

let log i =
    match i with
    | Message( indent, str ) ->
        str
        |> printfn "Message () %s%s" ( String.replicate ( indent * 4 ) " " )
    | Error( err ) ->
        err.ToString()
        |> printfn "Error () %s" 
    | Process( name, f ) ->
        printfn "Beginning %s..." name
        printfn "Completed %s\nReturn Code: %i" name <| f()
```

The compiler is correctly inferring the type for `indent`, `str` and `err`, but wants to infer `'a` and `'b` for `name` and `f` (which doesn't makes sense based either on the discriminated union or the usage). What's going on?

The error message:

```
Log.fs(18,16): error FS0001: This expression was expected to have type
    string * unit -> int    
but here has type
    'a * 'b
```

Answer (score 3):

Oops... figured it out.

I've incorrectly defined the type. I meant to take a string and a function accepting unit and returning int. Instead, I defined a function taking a string and unit and returning int. Here's how I corrected the definition in my discriminated union:

```
type LogInput =
    | Message of (int * string)
    | Error of Exception
    | Process of ( string * ( unit -> int ) )
```

Classic case of confusing operator precendence. See here for more:

[Symbol and Operator Reference (F#)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233228.aspx)

`*` has a higher precendence than `->`, so the tuple of `string` and `unit` won out over the definition of the function `unit -> int`

Comment: The operator precedence is this way because it is much more common to write a function that takes a tuple (for example, .NET methods are defined this way), than a tuple where one of the elements is a function (which is what you want here).

Comment: @Tarmil - Agreed, that is the more common use-case and it makes sense. But, being fairly new to the language, once I had it in my head that `string * unit -> int` meant `string * ( unit -> int)`, I couldn't quite figure out what was going on. If the compiler output was more explicit (like `(string * unit) -> int`), I would have recognized the error immediately.